# Calculating 3^3^3^3 (very large exponent / how did Wolfram do it?)

Tags: algorithm, math, largenumber, wolframalpha

I can't find a right algorithm / struct to calculate the number simply in C or Go. However, a class can easily be created in Python.

At first glance, the calculation seems to be very straight forward. However, when you look at the sample calculation from Wolfram Alpha.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E3%5E3%5E3

This breaks both `long long` (integer, 18-19 digits) and `double` (float / IEEE 754, up to e+308 digits, with 17 digits' precision).

However, I can cheat a little with Python, as it will automatically allocate more bytes for integer.

Still, 3^(7.625e+13) takes abnormally very long time... (3^3^3 = 7.625e+13).

```py
import math
from decimal import Decimal


class Int:
    _first = ""
    _last = ""
    _length = None  # Int

    val: int = None  # actual int, if applicable

    def __init__(self, val: int = 0) -> None:
        if isinstance(val, Int):
            if val.val is None:
                self._first = val._first
                self._last = val._last
                self._length = val._length
                return
            self.val = val.val
        else:
            self.val = val

        try:
            float(self.val)
        except OverflowError:
            self._first = self.first
            self._last = self.last
            self._length = self.length

            self.val = None

    @property
    def first(self) -> str:
        if self._first:
            return self._first

        return str(self.val)[:8]

    @property
    def last(self) -> str:
        if self._last:
            return self._last

        return str(self.val)[-8:]

    @property
    def length(self):
        if self._length:
            return self._length

        return Int(len(str(self.val)))

    def exp3(self):
        return Int(3) ** self.val

    def tetrate3(self, n: int):
        first = Int(self)
        for _ in range(n - 1):
            first = first.exp3()

        return first

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if self.val is None:
            return f"{self.first}...{self.last} ({self.first[0]}.{self.first[1:]}e+{self.length})"

        return f"{self.val}"

    def __pow__(self, _other):
        base = Int(self)
        exp = Int(_other)

        if base.val and exp.val:
            try:
                float(base.val) ** exp.val
                return Int(base.val ** exp.val)
            except OverflowError:
                pass

        log = Decimal(exp.val) * Decimal(math.log10(base.val))
        fl = math.floor(float(log))

        out = Int()
        out._first = f"{(10 ** float(log - fl)):.7f}".replace(".", "")
        out._last = str(pow(int(base.last), exp.val, 10_000_000_000))[-8:]
        out._length = Int(fl)
        out.val = None

        return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # After the third digits may be imprecise
    # => 12579723...00739387 (1.2579723e+3638334640024)
    print(Int(3).tetrate3(4))
```

Comment: Please share more details. Is this even related to programming? Why not ask this on https://math.stackexchange.com/ to see whether there is a mathematical solution for this

Comment: @NicoHaase I think it is clearly an algorithm problem and an algorithm complexity problem.

Comment: `float(base.val)` limits to Python's float precision so you can't get more than 15 digits of precision. And 3^3^3^3 overflows `float` type so `float(exp.val) * math.log10(float(base.val))` won't work. Also it seems you're storing values as strings which is inefficient

Comment: I'm sorry, one can in fact compute 3^3^3^3 with a big computer. It only has a few trillion digits. I was thinking about 3^3^3^3^3.

Answer (score 4):

Wolfram Alpha is giving you an *approximate* answer, which is much easier than calculating an exact answer. Most likely it's using the transform `log(a^b) = b * log(a)` to calculate `log(3^3^3^3) = (3^3^3) log(3) = 7625597484987 * log(3)`, which works out to about `3638334640024.09968557` if you take logs base 10. You'll notice that the integer part of that gives you the number of digits, and if you take `10^0.09968557`, you end up with `1.2580143` or so. Wolfram worked it out to a few more digits than I did, but this is pretty basic stuff with logarithms and *not* as expensive as computing 3^3^3^3 in integer arithmetic.

They also give the "last few digits" as `6100739387`, but that's easily done using modular exponentiation: a recent version of Python will instantly return the same value for `pow(3, 3**3**3, 10_000_000_000)`. Even though the power is rather large, the numbers being multiplied never get more than 10 digits long, so everything is easy to work out, and repeated squaring provides a major shortcut for the exponentiation.

Comment: Worth noting that this is right on the edge... 4^4^4^4 or 3^3^3^3^3 would both be too large for that log trick to help... and Wolfram Alpha *doesn't* print a decimal approximation of either, although it still knows exactly how *many* digits 4^4^4^4 has. Lots of tricks up its sleeve!

Comment: Updated my algo, that doesn't speed up that much, even with memoization. I would like to know what WolframAlpha has its tricks...

Comment: How did you get that many precision of 3638334640024.09968557 = 21 significant digits. I only get 17-18 in Python. Masked by "3638334640024" = 13 digits lost;  making only 4 significant digits left in Python.

Comment: @Polv I don't quite understand those python code but you don't do any [modpow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) like `pow(3, 3**3**3, 10_000_000_000)`. It looks like you're calculating the whole number so obviously it'll be too slow. Just calculate the last digits with `pow` like that. Calculating more first digits is also trivial, just use a float type with higher precision like Decimal. Python's float uses [IEEE-754 double precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) which is precise to only about 15 digits and can't be used for this purpose

Comment: @phuclv my current code isn't slow, but 1. only first 3 digits are precise. 2. I can't do tower of 5 (3^3^3^3^3); it will crash. I also will need to read a little on modpow to apply to C, or other languages.

Comment: @NicoHaase I rephrased and asked this in https://math.stackexchange.com -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225574/how-do-i-calculate-the-first-digits-and-last-digits-of-33333-or-3

Comment: I am still confused, as how many of the first digits are precise? As for 17 digits are precise, I can fix that with Python's Decimal class.

Comment: @hobbs About the 4^4^4^4 you discussed in your first comment: The code in my answer can do that without problem. Just needs to keep more digits around. With 200 digits, I get 47 correct digits: 2.3610226714597313206877027497781794309461272914... × 10^8072304726028225379382630397085399030071367921738743031867082828418414481568309149198911814701229483451981557574771156496457238535299087481244990261351116. Takes about 9 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

WolframAlpha shows the first few digits and the number of digits:

> 1.25801429062749131786039069820328121551804671431659... × 10^3638334640024

We can do that ourselves in less than a millisecond by keeping just the first let's say 50 digits. Do it once where we round down all the time, so we get a lower bound of the real value. Do it again where we round *up* all the time so we get an *upper* bound of the real value. The digits where lower and upper bound match are correct:

```
lower bound: 1.2580142906274913178603906982032812155096427774056 × 10^3638334640024
correct:     1.2580142906274913178603906982032812155... × 10^3638334640024
upper bound: 1.2580142906274913178603906982032812155218895229290 × 10^3638334640024
0.0003557720046956092 seconds
```

If you want more correct digits, just keep more digits and the lower and upper bound will match for more digits. For example with `keep = 100`:

```
lower bound: 1.258014290627491317860390698203281215518046714316596015189674944381211011300017785310803884345530895 × 10^3638334640024
correct:     1.258014290627491317860390698203281215518046714316596015189674944381211011300017785310803... × 10^3638334640024
upper bound: 1.258014290627491317860390698203281215518046714316596015189674944381211011300017785310803933426563879 × 10^3638334640024
0.0004895620222669095 seconds
```

My code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRLbtswEN3zFLMpKCqyYscoUBhQN0UWXeQERmrI9ggWKn5AUnWKIOfIgXIwd0h9IjlAShgGOZ/35ivz15@0Wn8z9nI5YgVGn9Em@wxQbBjQ4Zz/0NK0HmEPXoM/YWcEugLMSR3NLLq28VDAT@WTlYiy86luELDDCacmD/gCd@@SiWtawH6U7@dPhNvbAu56Jt9a1XsxdmhK5wJrBxpy2O1qVfvdLnHYVBnIUvnauZJyejJaofLFUryHoCjoBlXivE0GUyGmMSv4Dr8RzXXYUv9BclawiOqZltysbtURigL4UZ8Vn3uHM7DF5FbLNO0gZ3bYOPzEs4BFspjgTGDEHKdPHW4KuKIJVconiMN1bjACFCPWpOCybcZ6axoROylw37AwGHOqtDMdBdmHPD@Q3/Qug0BMYqAG9jFMyCXFGzo7YxaTwSrmDNO@h6mQgpq/mncAQxF75QJWM13gk9vlI0XKc07/crvaPF7XouLP8gXeXqldv57xhTNWWS1Bu9yU/gS1NNp6OGgptTIWq/qpM/C1xNoPekq7pB3YBamF0kW1ZX5JMcRrIhgLk0nvr0vWz2M/jqyJS9xVp9v60KG1yGCdpuFHSzC6tIaz1pj/OjCZxZpG8NyZpvYJD4lywR4yuCdVhLlS0QojJYRhW@5ZqOE092RLqA@PhG5sTZS8C30fgtvwrCMTg/KgrcWD38SPF21/7ESe05W/vfLwYRssu4RGmPgcSfoCUoP9klwdHrQ6Oi4ul38)) represents a number as two integers `mantissa` and `exponent`, representing the number `mantissa × 10^exponent`. Whenever `mantissa` grows too large (more than `keep` digits), it removes digits from `mantissa` and increases `exponent` accordingly:

```python
def power(b, e):
    '''Compute b to the power of e.'''
    result = Int(1)
    while e:
        if e % 2:
            result *= b
        b *= b
        e //= 2
    return result

class Int:
    def __init__(self, mantissa, exponent=0):
        n = len(str(mantissa))
        if n > keep:
            remove = n - keep
            if round == 'down':
                mantissa //= 10**remove
            else:
                mantissa = -(-mantissa // 10**remove)
            exponent += remove
        self.mantissa = mantissa
        self.exponent = exponent
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Int(self.mantissa * other.mantissa,
                   self.exponent + other.exponent)
    def __str__(self):
        m = str(self.mantissa)
        e = self.exponent
        if len(m) > 1:
            e += len(m) - 1
            m = m[0] + '.' + m[1:]
        return f'{m} × 10^{e}'

from os.path import commonprefix
from timeit import default_timer as timer
t0 = timer()

keep = 50
round = 'down'
lower = str(power(Int(3), 3**3**3))
round = 'up'
upper = str(power(Int(3), 3**3**3))

m, e = lower.split(' × ')
M, E = upper.split(' × ')
assert e == E
m = commonprefix([m, M])

print('lower bound:', lower)
print('correct:    ', m + '...', '×', e)
print('upper bound:', upper)

print(timer() - t0, 'seconds')
```